# Output of for-loop in R in the wrong order in RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want to print one plot for each column in a df in a for-loop. I do something like this:

```
for (i in colnames(df)){
  p <- ggplot(...) # my ggplot call
  print(p)
}
```

This works fine in a regular .R script, but in an Markdown the plots are outputted in the wrong order (ie. not the same order as in `colnames(df)`). Any guesses as to why this happens? Thanks.

Comment: Can you insert some data and code to make this reproducible for us?

Comment: Your nested for loops should have different Index variables. for (i in for (j in...

Answer (score 2):

Just checked on a simple markdown using `mtcars`:

````
---
title: "Test"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
require(ggplot2)

for (i in colnames(mtcars)) {
  print(i)
  (p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(!!rlang::sym(i))) +
    geom_bar())
}
```
````

Gives me bar plots of all columns in `mtcars` in the right order:

```
##[1] "mpg"
##[1] "cyl"
##[1] "disp"
##[1] "hp"
##[1] "drat"
##[1] "wt"
##[1] "qsec"
##[1] "vs"
##[1] "am"
##[1] "gear"
##[1] "carb"
```

Maybe you could provide a minimal example of your data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I call ```print(i)``` as you did, my colnames are outputted in the correct order — but the order of the plots is still random.

Can't share examples of my data since it's sensitive personal data, but the structure is equivalent to the ```mtcars```data.